# Leadership in new team

Tags: leadership

A new working team was created few days ago in my company, I was usually natural leader on every team I worked on there. With no kind of differentiations in wages, just leadership.

In this new group, there is another like me, and it's very clear that he wants to be the leader as much as I do. So far, we didn't have any fight, but there were some tense moments between us.

How should I act? Is it healthy for the team having two people fighting for leadership? Should I let him be the leader?

Additional info that may be useful: In my company there are no team leaders, just a boss that mixes the teams.

Comment: Can you explain the role and expectations of a 'leader' in your organization?

Comment: You may have better luck in guidance in the "Workplace" StackExchange.

Comment: Can someone migrate it then?

Comment: @JoelBancroft-Connors Questions asking "what should I do" are off-topic at Workplace. It is certainly off-topic here, but to be on-topic at workplace the OP needs to decide their strategy and then ask for how to implement it. VTC as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about Project Management but about how the OP should behave in order to coexist with another aspirational leader in the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good leader is a leader that can be led on! How about leading by example? Setting a good example of how a leader can be also a follower, and when the other leader sees your humbleness and when in times of doubt or failure, you can help him/her.